# Spring Batch JMSItemReader giving duplicate data in session transacted mode

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-batch, spring-transactions, spring-jms

I have a spring batch job which has single step. I am using JMSItemReader where jmstemplate is session transacted and my writer is just performing some business logic. Whenever any exception occurs by default and retry is exhausted then automatically batch size becomes 1 and retrys for all the items one by one.

I am defining step like this.

```
stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
                .<String, String> chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .faultTolerant()
                .processorNonTransactional()
                .retry(SomeException.class)
                .retryLimit(2)
                .backOffPolicy(backOffPolicy)
                .skip(SomeException.class)
                .skipLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                .build();
```

The issue I am facing is something like this 
Input is : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

1. Items in batch 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
2. Exception occurs in writer
3. Retrys for 2 times and retrys exhausted
4. Now it will try 1 by 1 like this

   item - 1 - Error

   item - 2 - Success

   item - 3 - Error

   item - 4 - Error

   item - 5 - Success

**As error occurred so items 1, 3, 4 are skipped and 2, 5 are successfully processed**

5. Here is the issue - Next I should get 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 as batch for processing but I am getting 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 as batch again and its getting executing infitely.

**Note: It works fine when the sessionTransacted is false but in that case it doesn't roll back messages in  case of exception to ActiveMQ Queue.**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is valid behavior, Since there is transaction rollback and message is not removed from queue, message is available for next listener thread for reading. And you've skip limit of Integer.MAX_VALUE, hence it would retry for infinite time(nearly as you have large skiplimit). I believe you need to configure dead letter queue for the queue you are reading from such that, after certain retries, if the message is corrupt/invalid, should be moved to `DLQ`, for manual intervention to process the message. Thus the same message is not redelivered again to the listener.

Comment: Can you please point me towards how to set up DLQ at client side using java configurations?

Comment: You need to configure on server side not in client side, only thing you can configure on client side is TimeToLive, which is not the case in your implementation, as you want to remove the messages which are invalid. Here is the configuration on the server side. http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html